# Increasing PR curve?

Tags: roc, precision-recall, precision

Usually PR curves are decreasing (like as precision decreases, recall increases). 
How would you justify/interpret an increasing precision recall curve?

The only way I can explain this is that the features used are not proper/informative (hence not resulting in a rational decision-making by the classifier). Otherwise, PR curve should always be a compromise between precision and recall (i.e. when one goes up, the other one should go down). 
I wonder if anyone has a better intuition/interpretation.

Here is an example I am getting in my project:

[image]

Comment: What does the scatterplot look like?

Comment: scatterplot of what?

Comment: What do you think? Precision and recall, of course...

Comment: Not clear what exactly you're talking about ...

Comment: Based on your description, PR sounds like a ratio of two metrics. If so, then create a scatterplot. If not, please clarify what the PR is.

Comment: By PR, I'm referring to the precision-recall curve: https://www.quora.com/What-is-Precision-Recall-PR-curve

Comment: Thanks. Got it. Still looks like doing some exploratory work that would decompose the graph into its component parts would potentially be insightful. This includes scatterplots, the bedrock for much exploratory analysis. Is there an issue with this suggestion?